# What kind of puppets/dolls is Thunderbolt Fantasy using?

Tags: anime-production, thunderbolt-fantasy

I have been watching *Thunderbolt Fantasy* and have been wondering what kind of puppets/dolls they are using.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_Fantasy) that Good Smile Company were one of the collaborators on it's production and since Good Smile sells figma one could assume they are using figma however i have noticed finger movements and figma have noticeable joints and i see no joints in the fingers

So what kind of puppets/dolls is *Thunderbolt Fantasy* using?

Comment: The same Wikipedia page you linked says they use glove puppetry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glove_puppetry